# Create variables dynamically inside loop in python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create some buttons dynamically for Python and Kivy based on an external file.

So far, I managed to web scrape the file, read it and create widgets with it. The problem is that I need those widgets to have a unique var name and I can't see a way to achieve this.

```
def build(self):
    #main layout
    menu_box = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")
    #web scraping
    try:
        WebLeida = request.urlopen("http://coznothingisforever.webs.com/Yoloplanner/Yoloplanner.txt").read().decode('utf8')
        WebParsed = ast.literal_eval(WebLeida)
        #for each item
        for i in WebParsed:
            #create a button
            boton = Button(font_size=16,
                            size_hint_y=None,
                            height=100,
                            text=i["dia"] + " - " + i["hora"])
            #bind the events
            boton.bind(print("testing"))
            #add the new created button to the layout
            menu_box.add_widget(boton)
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")
    #run the main layout
    return menu_box
```

The problem with this is that all the buttons would be named "boton", so when I need to use specific functions like boton.bind the program won't know which one to use.

This is the desired outpost, but with unique var names:
[image]

Any suggestions?
Also, is web scraping the best way to achieve this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856891/how-can-i-make-a-lot-of-buttons-at-dynamic-in-kv-language/35867156#35867156) might be helpful for you.

Comment: it is a bit brutish but have you tried inside the for: `exec("self.boton"+str(i)) = ...`
 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why no one posted this as an answer even if it is in `python` tag. Every widget in kivy is an object, so it's there when you create it and you don't have to use a variable directly, just `Button(...)` in a line for example. Therefore it's in `kv` file so easy to design your app in this way:

```
<Root_widget>:
    SomeWidget:
        Button_1:
        ...
        Button_N:
```

No variable, however if you want, you can pass `id` to your widget, which are then collected to `ids` dictionary. And there comes something similar as ids. You can freely create your own dictionary and add every Button you like to it in a way like this:

```
my_buttons['new_button'] = Button(font_size=16, size_hint_y=None, height=100,
                                  text=i["dia"] + " - " + i["hora"])
```

If you bind, it'll be like `<xyz object at somewhere>.bind()` and in an example it'd look like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from functools import partial

class Box(BoxLayout):
    buttons={}
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Box, self).__init__(**kw)
        for i in range(10):
            self.buttons[str(i)]=Button(text=str(i))
            self.add_widget(self.buttons[str(i)])
            self.buttons[str(i)].bind(on_release=partial(self.ping, str(i)))
    def ping(self, *arg):
        print 'test',str(arg)
class My(App):
    def build(self):
        return Box()
My().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you care about what the id is?
If its just uniqueness then

```
import uuid
id = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

If you care about what the id is could do

```
id_template = 'button_id_{0}'
count = 1
for i in WebParsed:
   button_id = id_template.format(count)
   count += 1
```