# need to display a list of objects on popup or window kivy

Tags: python, kivy

hello guys i have a list of objects in ce and upon clicking the results button i need a popup or window to come and too display the objects attritubutes to the user. e.g display the attribute legs for each object in ce

since i cannot write so many labels into the popup since i do not know how many objects are there in ce

and ce is a global variable

is there any way i can do that using a for loop

```
class drawing(App):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    def Results(self):
        Results_para().open()

class Results_para(Popup):
      pass
```

the kv file

```
<Results_para>:
   cols:2
   Label:
     text:'%d'%ce[0].legs
   .
    .

    .
```

any suggestions

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [How can I make a lot of buttons at dynamic in kv language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856891), but that one does not have an accepted or upvoted answer. In short: not in `kv`, at least not without some hackery (jligeza's answer). My (downvoted) answer shows a way to do it in kv lang, but it's ugly.